# Laravel route Resource breaks another route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

When I use my route like this, the `test` route is  working fine.
Route:-

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => '\User'), function () {
Route::get('user/my-favorite','UserController@myFavorite');
Route::get('user/test','UserController@test'); // is working
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
Route::get('user/planed',['as' => 'user.planed', 'uses' => 'USerController@planed']);
.
.
.
.
```

But when I want to use it like following, it  shows a blank page :

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => '\User'), function () {
Route::get('user/my-favorite','UserController@myFavorite');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
Route::get('user/planed',['as' => 'user.planed', 'uses' => 'UserController@planed']);
Route::get('user/test','UserController@test'); // is not working
.
.
.
.
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working?" what is happening exactly? I can see that you have the test route in the `auth` middleware group, so maybe that could be why. But again, can you please clarify what exactly is happening?

Comment: @AaronFahey `test` method in controller prints a query output : `$users = Subscriber::where('user_id', $this->_userId)->pluck('user_id');
        dd($users);`   -  it is working before `resource` but shows a blank page after putting the route inside `Auth` middlware after `resource`

Comment: I am testing it by a logged in user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the call to test is intercepted by

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

because if you check the routes in the console with

```
$> php artisan route:list
```

you'll see it includes

```
GET|HEAD  | user/{user}
```

and then your first route

```
Route::get('user/test','UserController@test'); // is not working
```

is never reached. Try to put it BEFORE the other line.

Comment: You mean route `resource` for `User`  should be put after all `user` routes?  I thought laravel `Resource` only  intercept  `index`, `create` , `update ` ,....  routes!!

Comment: as you see `user/planed` route is working, and it is after `resource`

Comment: When I use the route like this: `Route::get('user/test/{id}','UserController@test');`, it is working!!!  why? I do not need `id` wild card

Comment: Did you at least try what I suggested?

Comment: Yes @Amarnasan, I tried and it worked!  but what is wrong with my code ?   Do I have to always put all routes after `Resourse` route ?

Comment: First off, when an answer work, check it as "correct". It is a way of saying "Thanks for your time in helping me". As for the rest, my answer is quite clear. You just need to be careful in the order you write routes, and read the documentation on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I thing the issue in naming the route check [This](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes)

Try like this

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => '\User'), function () {
Route::get('user/my-favorite','UserController@myFavorite');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
Route::get('user/planed','UserController@planed'])->name('user.planed');
Route::get('user/test','UserController@test'); // is not working
```

Just replace

```
Route::get('user/planed',['as' => 'user.planed', 'uses' => 'UserController@planed']);
```

With

```
Route::get('user/planed','UserController@planed'])->name('user.planed');
```

Comment: Tried, didn't work.  event is I put `test` route just after `resource`, is not working!  blank page without error

Comment: Your `['middleware' => ['auth']]` is working fine or not ?

Comment: Yes it it is working for other routes in this middleware

Comment: When I use the route like this: `Route::get('user/test/{id}','UserController@test');`, it is working!!!  why? I do not need `id` wild card

Comment: Just change the route name as`test2` and remove `{id}` and try it again

Comment: I changed the name several times, no difference, anyway tried one more time! not working

Comment: Once again try like this `Route::get('/user/testFinal','UserController@test');`

Comment: Didn't work.  when I put it just before `resource` it worked. so weird